# iOS Storyboard: Different Layouts for Different Devices

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, size-classes

[image]

As you can see, this is the different device previews for my current storyboard. The transparent green on the bottom is taken up by another view controller, but the spacing needs to be fixed for each different size class. I tried setting the width and height in the storyboard to the setting I want to change, but it changes that attribute for all the size classes. How can I just change, for example, the size of the Label at the top for ONLY 3.5in iPhones or the green layout for ONLY 5.5in iPhones?

Comment: As I'm aware 3.5,4.0 and 4.7 inch iPhone have the same size class.So I think you can't.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the spacing needs to be fixed for each different size class"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want all device layouts to look like the iPhone 4.7in device (the third image)

Comment: @jaytj95 - have you found any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Choose the pin of the label and go to Attributes Inspector of the Utility Area. You can find + button left to the constant text field.

[image]

When you tap the button, you can choose the size class you need.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain further?